# My game doesn't sign in to Google Play Games

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to implement achievements and a leaderboard for a small game I'm coding, but for some reasonI can't make Google Play Games to sign in to be able to perform all the operations. It displays the logging window but always says 'Sign in error'

I've looked to many answers and tutorial, as well as the Google documentation for signing in, but I just can't make it to work. Here is my code.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    logro = findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    leader = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-6138983841028001/11111111");
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    logro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showAchievements();

        }
    });

    leader.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showLeaderboard();

        }
    });

    signIn();

}

private void signIn() {
    System.out.println("HA ENTRADO");
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, 9001);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 9001) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // The signed in account is stored in the result.
            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
        } else {
            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = "Sign in error";
            }
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    }
}

private void showLeaderboard() {
    Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_pasos))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            });
}

private void showAchievements() {
    Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
            .getAchievementsIntent()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when your forget or incorrectly setup the correct SHA-1 fingerprint of your Android app. You probably missing the following steps from [Authenticate Using Google Play Games Services on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/play-games):

```
1. Set your game's SHA-1 fingerprint from the Settings page of the Firebase console.

You can get the SHA-1 fingerprint of your key with the keytool command:

keytool -exportcert -list -v \
    -alias YOUR-KEY-NAME -keystore PATH-TO-KEYSTORE


2. Enable Google Play Games as a sign-in provider:

Find your project's web server client ID and client secret. The web server client ID identifies your Firebase project to the Google Play auth servers.

To find these values:

Open your Firebase project in the Google APIs console credentials page.
In the OAuth 2.0 client IDs section, open the Web client (auto created by Google Service) details page. This page lists your web server client ID and secret.
Then, in the Firebase console, open the Authentication section.

On the Sign in method tab, enable the Play Games sign-in provider. You will need to specify your project's web server client ID and client secret, which you got from the APIs console.
```

**Do not forget** to recheck if you've already `enable the Play Games sign-in provider`, which I usually missed to recheck.

You can also use [Firebase assistant](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase) in your Android Studio.

Comment: I had to setup my SHA-1 fingerprint several times, but finally it worked. Thanks!!